# Problem 301 redirect not allowing login in the backend

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I am finding some problems in the htaccess of CMS with a 301 redirect.

When trying to solve canonical urls (redirecting site to www.site) I got the problem that I cannot log in in the back end (`www.site/admin`).

The htaccess condition is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]
```

I guess I need to include a expression that allows the URI `/admin` not to be redirected, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Like this, for example:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks LazyOne, will keep this post bookmarked for future reference. You save my day! Cheers

Comment: @Seosmart You are welcome. If this answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted, thnx.